# Segmentation fault using Swift Accelerate vDSP_ctoz

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I'm trying to convert an interleaved `DSPComplex` vector to a `DSPSplitComplex` vector, using `vDSP_ctoz` from the Swift Accelerate library. The last line of the code below produces the error `Segmentation fault: 11`

I don't understand why `vDSP_ctoz` would try to access out-of-bound memory when I've allocated large vectors and am only trying to process a small number of elements. The vectors are size 2048 and the argument for `N` (number of elements to process) in `vDSP_ctoz` is 1.

I've also tried using different stride and `N` values when calling `vDSP_ctoz`, to no avail.

```
// set stride values
let dspComplexStride = MemoryLayout<DSPComplex>.stride
let dspSplitComplexStride = MemoryLayout<DSPSplitComplex>.stride

// make interleaved vector
var interleaved = UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPComplex>.allocate(capacity: 2048)
for index in 0..<16 {
    interleaved[index] = DSPComplex(real: Float(2*index), imag: Float(2*index+1))
}

// make split vector
var splitComplex = UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPSplitComplex>.allocate(capacity: 2048)
vDSP_ctoz(
    interleaved, dspComplexStride, splitComplex, dspSplitComplexStride, 1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DSPSplitComplex` is a structure *containing* pointers arrays,
so you need a single `DSPSplitComplex` element and must allocate
storage for its `realp` and `imagp` properties.

The "stride" arguments are not measured in bytes but in "element" units.
So you pass `__IZ == 1` because you want to fill contiguous elements
in the destination arrays.

It may not be obvious that you have to pass `__IC == 2` for the source array, i.e.
the stride of the source array is given in `Float` units and not in 
`DSPComplex` units. This can be deduced from the [`vDSP_ctoz` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450388-vdsp_ctoz)
which mentions that the function effectively does

```
for (n = 0; n < N; ++n)
{
  Z->realp[n*IZ] = C[n*IC/2].real;
  Z->imagp[n*IZ] = C[n*IC/2].imag;
}
```

Finally, the last argument of `vDSP_ctoz` is the number of elements to
process.

Putting it all together, this is how it should work:

```
import Accelerate

let N = 16

var interleaved = UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPComplex>.allocate(capacity: N)
for index in 0..<N {
    interleaved[index] = DSPComplex(real: Float(2*index), imag: Float(2*index+1))
}

let realp = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: N)
let imagp = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: N)
var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: realp, imagp: imagp)

vDSP_ctoz(interleaved, 2, &splitComplex, 1, vDSP_Length(N))

for index in 0..<N {
    print(splitComplex.realp[index], splitComplex.imagp[index])
}
```

and of course you have to release the memory eventually.